# How to read wrapper class in java with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

How would I read a Farm object from a JSON file?

```
public class Farm(){
        private Animal cat;
        private String name;
        private int age;
}
public class Animal(){
        private int legs;
}
```

I am using the below code to write a Farm object to a file.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();                   
ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)));
mapper.writeValue(out, farmobj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Farm farm = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\farm.json"), Farm.class);
```

Is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, will this still be able to be used for multiple Farm objects in the JSON file?

Comment: If you have JSON array, you can try mapping to `Farm[]` replacing `Farm` with `Farm[]` on the left and on the right.

Comment: {"Animal":{"this":"blahblahblah","amount":"blahblahblah"},"name":"cat","age":"blahblah"}

This is the output I'm trying to read.